# Showing existence of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|>4\}$. Show that there exists a holomorphic function on $D$ whose derivative is $\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)}=f(z)$.

My idea so far:
Using partial fraction decomposition, we see that $f(z)=\frac{1}{2(z-1)} +\frac{3}{2(z-3)} -2\frac{1}{z-2}$.

Then, since $f$ is continuous on the domain $D$, we take any piecewise continuous differentiable closed path $\gamma$ in $D$ and we get:

$\int_\gamma f(z)dz =\frac{1}{2}n(\gamma ;1)+ \frac{3}{2}n(\gamma ;3)-2n(\gamma ;2)=0$, where the last inequality follows from the fact that 1,2, and 3 are all contained in the same connected component $\mathbb{C} \setminus [\gamma]$, so they all have the same winding numbers with respect to $\gamma$. ($n(\gamma ; a)$ denoting the winding number $\gamma$ around the point $a$)

This, since $D$ is a domain and f is continuous on $D$ and the integral about every piecewise continuous differentiable closed path in the domain is 0, $f$ must have an anti derivative on $D$.

What I would like to know is, if the above argument is true, is this anti derivative guaranteed to be holomorphic on $D$?

Comment: I'm confused. What's your definition of holomorphic function? Isn't a holomorphic function a differentiable function whose domain is an open set, or something similar to this? (By the way, this is the definition that I work with.)

Comment: What you wrote is correct. $f$ is even *holomorphic* in $D$, and the integral over every closed path is zero. That implies that $f$ has an antiderivative (which by definition is holomorphic).

Comment: You can, however, just integrate $f$ directly to get a suitable function.

Comment: another option would be to write the Laurent Series for $f$ (for $4 \lt \vert z \vert \lt \infty$), observe all terms have a negative power, and crucially $a_{-1}=0$, which allows you to explicitly write out the Laurent Series for a choice $F(z)$ where $F'(z)=f(z)$.